# Is there a way to PRINT css gradients in Opera

Tags: css, opera

I have a simple page which I want to print into PDF file, however no matter what kind of styles/prefixes for the gradient I use, it will never appear in the pdf file. Even though I have "print background images" option on and I can see the gradient on the printing preview. Any ideas?

@edit: Noticed that the gradients don't display only when I use default Windows 8 PDF Reader.

Comment: We would need a little bit more information. If I understand you correctly you have a webpage that incorporates a CSS background gradient and are viewing the page using Opera as the browser. You are trying to use Adobe to create a pdf from what is essentially a 'printscreen' or print to file option. The problem is that CSS is not creating an image such as jpg or png or gif so Adobe does not recognize it as a background image.

Comment: Updated - when I use Adobe Reader to view the file the gradients display correctly. They don't display, however, when I use default widnows pdf reader.

Comment: Are you viewing the file as a saved pdf file that Adobe created already or are you trying to preview what the pdf would look like using Adobe Reader and Windows PDF Viewer?

Comment: I'm viewing a saved pdf file

Comment: Perhaps someone can give advice on the Windows PDF Reader. That is your problem.